# How to call a second method when another first method returns true?

Tags: java

I have two methods here.  I want the void levelUp to check if the checkWin method returns true. It it does I would then like it to call the initLevel method with the parameters ++currentLevel. This is what I have so far but it is not behaving as I would like. Any suggestions? Thanks, Tim

```
void levelUp(boolean checkWin) {
    if (checkWin) {
        initLevel(++currentLevel); 
        return;
    }
}  

public boolean checkWin () {
    for (int i=0; i < levelData.length;i++) {
        for (int k=0; k < levelData[i].length;k++) {
            if (levelData[i][k] == Contents.BOX) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Use checkWin(), you forgot the ()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two step implementation of Hovercraft's answer.

1. Change `if (checkWin)` to `if (checkWin())`.
2. Delete the parameter `checkWin`.

Answer (score 4):

Your `levelUp()` method never calls the `checkWin()` method: It just uses the boolean parameter that confusingly has the same name as the `checkWin` method.

If you want to call the `checkWin()` method inside of `levelUp()`, then do that: call the actual method (you'll need to add some brackets after the method name).

Comment: Thank you @Bohemian. 1+ to merlin2011 as well.